# Excel Macro Delete Columns Based on User Preference

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie here...have used this site many times to get answers but can't find one for my latest challenge.

I would like to create a macro in which a user will select (mark/unmark) field names in one sheet, run the macro which will re-order, format etc data on another sheet and remove columns the user didn't want to see.

Ex: User wants to see columns data elements A,B & D but not C so they mark those three rows in sheet one and leave dataC blank.

```
Sheet1
Field Name(Column A)    Include? (Column B)
DataA                    Y
DataB                    
DataC                    Y
DataD                    Y
```

Macro runs and creates a sheet2 which retains all fields from a standard export file ...currently 50+ fields but for this example lets say there are only 4

Ideally, the result will be a sheet2 with the following columns only.

```
DataA  DataB  DataC
```

I've already created a macro that does the formatting. Is there something I can add at the end to delete certain columns based on the info from sheet1?

Any and all help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

-------------------This is one macro of a whole bunch i wanted to consolidate hence my question. Instead of trying to maintain different macros and requiring people to export on certain fields from the source system, I thought it would be easier auto-export data, people just mark what they need and run the macro. Thanks

```
Sub ARMImport()
'
' Upload1 Macro
'

'
    Dim FileToOpen
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename
    If FileToOpen <> False Then
    Workbooks.OpenText FileToOpen, Origin:= _
        65001, StartRow:=1, DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=True, Tab:=False, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array( _
        3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10 _
        , 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1), Array(16, 1), _
        Array(17, 1), Array(18, 1), Array(19, 1), Array(20, 1), Array(21, 1), Array(22, 1), Array( _
        23, 1), Array(24, 1), Array(25, 1), Array(26, 1), Array(27, 1), Array(28, 1), Array(29, 1), _
        Array(30, 1), Array(31, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
        Else
        MsgBox "No file selected. Macro cancelled."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ActiveWorkbook.Unprotect ("deleted")
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect ("deleted")
    Rows(Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).Delete
    Columns("K:JA").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("J8").Activate
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Columns("H:J").Select
    Range("J8").Activate
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateInputOnly, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator _
        :=xlBetween
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("K8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "#"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=1).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("L8").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Entered By" & vbCrLf & "(f_boX.entered_by)"
    Range("E4").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("L9").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("M8").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Box Status" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.status)"
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("M9").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "A"
    Range("M10").Select
    Range("K9").Value = InputBox("redacted question?")
    Dim LR As Long
    LR = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("L9:M9").Select
        Selection.Copy
        Range("L9:M" & LR).Select
        ActiveSheet.Paste
    LRZ = Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("K9").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("K9:K" & LRZ), Type:=xlFillSeries
    Rows("1:8").Select
    Range("A8").Activate
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Vendor Barcode" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.external_name)"
    Range("B1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "User Box Number" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.cust_user_box_number)"
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Department" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.office_id)"
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Description" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.notes)"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=11).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("E1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "additional Description" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.notes2)"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=22).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("F1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "From Date" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.cust_from_date)"
    Range("G1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "To Date" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.cust_to_date)"
    Range("H1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Box Type" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.box_type)"
    Range("I1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Media Type" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.cust_media_type)"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=10).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Regular"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("J1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Category" & vbCrLf & "(category_import_id [fullcode] )"
    Range("K1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "#"
    Range("L1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "BoX owner" & vbCrLf & "(f_boX.owner )"
    Range("M1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Box Status" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.status)"
    Columns("K:K").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Columns("L:L").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("B1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Entered By" & vbCrLf & "(f_boX.entered_by)"
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("C:C").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("C1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Box Number" & vbCrLf & "f_box.box_num"
    Columns("D:D").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("G1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Foreign Barcode" & vbCrLf & "(Barcode)"
    Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Cut
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Cells.Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection.Font
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Rows("1:1").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = True
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Dim LRF As Long
    LRF = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("A1:P" & LRF).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin
        End With
        Columns("P:P").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("P1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Storage Location" & vbCrLf & "(f_box.warehouse_id)"
    With ActiveCell.Characters(Start:=1, Length:=16).Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .FontStyle = "Bold"
        .Size = 11
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Range("P2").Value = InputBox("redacted question?")
    Dim LRST As Long
    LRST = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("P2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("P2:P" & LRST)
    Range("F2").Value = InputBox("What is the Department ID?")
    Dim LRDI
    LRDI = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Range("F2").Select
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F" & LRDI)
    Sheets("Retention Schedule").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Sheets("Instructions").Select
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Rows("2:8").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A2").Select
    MsgBox "Macro Completed"
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's see your code

Comment: You could quickly use a Filter on that data, then copy visible and do whatever with that, no? What have you done so far?

Comment: I've only formatted the data and nothing else. The filter will not work because entire columns need to be deleted. Users will take resulting files and either forward to other groups or import to a system.

Comment: So you have no code written?  You are correct, if you want to modify the excel sheet by deleting or inserting cells, you will need VBA.

Comment: @BruceWayne Has your user icon always been white?  Or have you changed it be very light so that people don't mistake you for the "Dark Knight"?

Comment: I do have code written which preps/formats all the fields in sheet2. My question is is there a code i can add that will delete columns based on info from sheet1. Sorry, i can't share the code as is....will need time to go through it and rename certain references like field names or new cell value adds. I should note, sheet2 is created from a file exported from a db. that's why rename/re-order columns etc is needed.

Comment: Once you post your redacted code, it should be relatively easy for someone to suggest some minor alteration to get it to do what you want.  Until then, people would be guessing wildly as to what would be the best method to suggest.

Comment: @YowE3K - I actually don't recall - although, why someone would confuse me with that amazing (and handsome) hero of Gotham anyways, I am not sure!